# Can't get into Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, login

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 and now I can't log in. It's giving me the lock screen with my name and password. I put my password in and it just stays the same.

I notice that there's another user logged in. That's me, because there is only 1 user on each of my machines and I'm set to automatic login.

What can I do, please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the fault myself. Because I noticed that I was already logged in, I re-booted and tried CTRL-ALT-BACKSPACE. That got me to another menu which had emergency things on it. I tried it and got in. Then I opened SETTINGS and changed the USER to log in. Then I re-booted and got the same screen, but I logged in and was taken to the desktop.

Chris